# Delayed Acknowledging GCloud Pub/Sub message

Tags: c++11, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to implement a PubSub client that acts like AWS or Azure queues, however, I am facing problems with gcloud cpp sdk.

UPDATED: removed unnecessary details.

First of all, the provided [example](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#receive_messages) does not work out of the box - I had to put a sleep before `session.cancel()`, otherwise the message was not acknowledged.  Is there a solid way to wait until the ack() operation is finished and check its status? At least I want to be sure that the server received my request.

Besides, the c++ API seems to provide only an asynchronous method that does not fit my use-case.

I need to implement the following interface that is plugged into a larger system via dependency injection. The system works in production on other clouds so I cannot change the architecture. Just need to implement the interface.

```
template<typename TItem>
class Queue{
public:
    /*!
    * Dequeues message from the queue 
    * Returns true on success
    */
    virtual bool Dequeue( TItem & item) = 0;

    /*!
    * Discards(deletes) the item with from the cloud queue.
    */
    virtual void Discard(const TReceipt & receipt) = 0;
};
```

The actual implementation of the queue will be fed with a serializer that serializes TItem to JSON and back.

AWS and Azure SDKs provide a receipt for each dequeued message so that I can discard it later. The receipt of the pubsub SDK is the AckHandler object, that is bound to the session.

An obviously wrong solution would be to keep the session open and in the lambda wait for another condition_variable until the next time the Dequeue method is called. However, this looks like a quick and dirty solution.
What is the proper way to implement this functionality with Pub/Sub?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a solid way to wait until the ack() operation is finished and check its status?

Not really, because `ack()` operations are best-effort.  Even if you wait for the `ack()` to get to the server, that is no guarantee that the message will not be resent.  Yes, the service may resend the message even after a successful `ack()`.

Note that the library automatically extends the lease on your messages to avoid resends until your explicitly `ack()` or `nack()`, so delays in the `ack()` do not affect correctness *unless* you close the application shortly after the `ack()`.

> AWS and Azure SDKs provide a receipt for each dequeued message so that I can discard it later, but I cannot figure out how to do that with pub/sub.

You can call `nack()` on the `AckHandler` to discard a message, meaning the message will be resent to another instance.  Is that what you mean by "discard"?

> What is the proper way to implement this functionality with Pub/Sub?

Hmm I am not sure I follow.  I can take a guess at the semantics of `Dequeue()` and `Discard()`, apologies if I guess wrong.  In any case, it is not clear if this is really supposed to work with any type?  Like `TReceipt == int`?

With the caveat that there is a lot of guessing here, you can do something like this:

```cpp
class PubsubBuffer {
 private:
  std::mutex mu_;
  std::dequeue<std::pair<pubsub::Message, AckHandlerWrapper>> queue_;

 public:
  virtual bool Dequeue(pubsub::Message& item, AckHandlerWrapper& receipt) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mu_);
    if (queue_.empty()) return false;
    auto& f = queue_.front();
    item = std::move(f.first);
    receipt = std::move(.second);
    queue_.pop_front();
    return true;
  }
  virtual void Discard(AckHandlerWrapper const& receipt) {
    std::move(receipt.ack_handler).ack();
  }
  void Push(pubsub::Message m, pubsub::AckHandler h) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mu_);
    queue_.push_back(
      std::make_pair(std::move(m), AckHandlerWrapper(std::move(h)));
  }
};


std::shared_ptr<PubsubBuffer> F(pubsub::Subscriber s) {
  auto buffer = std::make_shared<PubsubBuffer>();
  auto handler = [buffer](pubsub::Message m, pubsbu::AckHandler h) {
    buffer.Push(std::move(m), std::move(h));
  };
  return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Hi @coryan. Thanks for the answer. I have updated the question to avoid unnecessary details. 
In your example, the publisher and the subscriber should be in the same process. In my case the publishers are our clients that publish the tasks. 

Let us assume that the `hash` function and `operator==` are overloaded for TItem and we can keep an `unordered_map` from TItem to its AckHandler so that we can find it on demand. 

I just need to dequeue a single message, process it, and then delete it on success.

Comment: "In your example, the publisher and the subscriber should be in the same process."

I do not think so.  I just assumed that you would feed this queue from the handler of some Subscriber.


Can you share more about the semantics of that `Queue<TItem>` interface in your (updated) question?  Is the expectation that each `Dequeue()` results in a RPC to get a message from Cloud Pub/Sub?  Or you want to have a buffer of ready messages in your local process?

Comment: Yes, each Dequeue results in a RPC. 
The processing time of a message varies from a few seconds to about 5 min so we set the invisibility timeout to 600 secs.

Comment: The code in the main thread looks like

`while( !queue->Empty() ) {
   if(queue->Dequeue(item)) {
      /*Process the message*/
      queue->Discard(item);    
   }
}`

Another problem is how to determine if the queue is empty without using deprecated parameters, but this is a matter of a different question.

Comment: Seems like you want to pull one message at a time, leaving any other messages in the Pub/Sub service?  We do not offer that API because generally, it yields very poor throughput, but there is a way to do something similar.  Set the `max_outstanding_messages()` to `1` in your `SubscriberOption`: https://googleapis.dev/cpp/google-cloud-pubsub/latest/classgoogle_1_1cloud_1_1pubsub_1_1v1_1_1SubscriberOptions.html . The service will wait for an ack before sending the next message.

Comment: I updated my code to explain how you would connect it to a subscriber. HTH